# how's i can calling to int from def in class?

Tags: python, function, class

i have this code:

```
  class PLAYER:
    def player_move(self):
       if self.new_block == True:
           body_copy = self.body[:]
           body_copy.insert(0,body_copy[0] + self.direction)
           self.body = body_copy[:]
           self.new_block = False
           self.score += 1
   #print(self.score)
```

i want to calling self.score from outside the PLAYER class

Comment: There's no `self` outside the method. You need to create an instance, then you can use `instance.score`

Comment: `self` refers to an instance of class `PLAYER`. You can call it on such an object after defining it. For example : `player = PLAYER(); player.score`

Comment: Also worth noting: in your method you are using attributes that don't exist yet. It is safer to define them in a `__init__` method which will automatically set them when you call for an instance of that class (when you execute `player = PLAYER()`)

Comment: oh my....thnx for your helping <3

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor (the **init** method) as done below, and within the constructor you must define self.score, as well as all the other fields you want your PLAYER class to have. In the code below I am assuming that when you are initializing a PLAYER object that you are providing the new_block, direction, and body information, however you defined these fields, which is unclear from the question.

```
class PLAYER:
    def __init__(self, new_block,direction,body):
        self.score = 0
        self.new_block = new_block
        self.direction = direction
        self.body = body
    
    def player_move(self):
       if self.new_block == True:
           body_copy = self.body[:]
           body_copy.insert(0,body_copy[0] + self.direction)
           self.body = body_copy[:]
           self.new_block = False
           self.score += 1
```